# How to verify that email field is not blank before submitting form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, validation

**Updated Question:**

I added "required" to all fields, except the form will still submit if

first@second is used as the email. It submits even if missing the .com  (or whatever).

How can I incorporate this validation too?

Thanks!

**Original Question:**

My site has a sign-up form with just an email field. Currently there are validators in place to verify the proper syntax of an entered e-mail, but the form **will** submit if the field is left blank.  I need to verify that the field is not blank **before** submission. If it's blank, there should be some message that appears - similar to the ones that appear is no @ symbol is included for instance.

My demo page is [here.](http://jasoncampbell.net46.net/public/demo2.html)

The form html:

```
 <div class='form animated flipInX'>
  <h2>Sign Up</h2>
<form action="http://mydomain.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="u" value="a324dfsf32erwdafdaf3dfsdsdf">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="32df32rff2">

 <input type="email" name="MERGE0" id="MERGE0" placeholder="Your Email Address" class="boxfield">

    <button class='animated infinite pulse'>Let's Go!</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: return false if the validation fails or if `value` is `''`.

Comment: <input type="email" name="MERGE0" id="MERGE0" placeholder="Your Email Address" class="boxfield" required> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `required` in your input tags

The required attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form.

So your input should be

```
<input type="email" name="MERGE0" id="MERGE0" placeholder="Your Email Address" class="boxfield" required>
```

Look here for [more information](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Techniques/HTML5/Using_the_required_attribute_to_indicate_a_required_input_field)

**Update :**

`type="email"` is the common attribute of html5. If you need to validate you shall use the patten inside your input element

You shall use `pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)\b`

Here is the one use should use

```
<input type="email" required pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)\b">
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/du676/8/) as per your updated question

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. required works great, but I've updated my question because the form will still submit if 'first@second' is used as email, essentially missing the .com. How do I incorporate this validation too?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `required` attribute in input tags.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Using required works perfectly but the form will still submit if 'first@second' is used as email, essentially missing the .com.  How do I incorporate this validation too?  (Updated my question)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="email" name="MERGE0" id="MERGE0" placeholder="Your Email Address" class="boxfield" required="true">
```

Luckily it's that easy

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this to add `required` attribute in input tags

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution in which i using jquery to check it is blank or filled

```
<div class='form animated flipInX'>
<h2>Sign Up</h2>
<form action="http://mydomain.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post"  method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="u" value="a324dfsf32erwdafdaf3dfsdsdf">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="32df32rff2">
<input type="email" name="MERGE0" id="MERGE0" placeholder="Your Email Address" class="boxfield">
<button class='animated infinite pulse' type="submit" onClick="checkval();">Let's Go!</button>
 </form>
</div>
 <script>
  function checkval()
  {
     var email_val=$("#MERGE0").val();
     if(email_val.length>2) 
     {
     }
     else
     {
        alert("email is required.");/*there you change show the value which you want to show as a error message.*/
         event.preventDefault();
         /* this help to stop submit form*/ 
     }

   }
   </script>
```

hopefully this may help you

Comment: You are checking the length of the text that is being typed ??

Comment: yes it work to check it is not blank in html5 has a draw back when we enter a whitespaces it does not work when

Comment: So if i enter `xyz` it will consider it like an email right ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your question has been answer, but try this:

```
//The Input
<input type='email' id='email' placeholder='email' onchange='emailCheck()'>
//The Button
<button id='button' style='visibility:hidden'>Submit</button>
//Javascript
<script>
var input = document.getElementById('email').value;
if(input.indexOf("@") > -1){

if(input.indexOf(".com") >= input.length - 4){
document.getElementById('button').style.visibility = 'visible';
}else{
alert('Custom Invalid Email Alert');
}

}else{
alert('Custom Invalid Email Alert');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

required is best option or u can use java script

like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
          function validateForm()
        {
          var a=document.forms["Form"]["answer_a"].value;
        var b=document.forms["Form"]["answer_b"].value;
       var c=document.forms["Form"]["answer_c"].value;
        var d=document.forms["Form"]["answer_d"].value;
                   if (a==null || a=="",b==null || b=="",c==null || c=="",d==null             || d=="")
         {
           alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
          return false;
           }
        }
        </script>

          <form method="post" name="Form" onsubmit="return         validateForm()" action="">
           <textarea cols="30" rows="2" name="answer_a" id="a"></textarea>
             <textarea cols="30" rows="2" name="answer_b" id="b"></textarea>
           <textarea cols="30" rows="2" name="answer_c" id="c"></textarea>
           <textarea cols="30" rows="2" name="answer_d" id="d"></textarea>
      </form>
```